# I install matplotlib

Tags: python, windows

I am facing an issue with the below code, any help will be appreciated.

Error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1366, in <module>
    _rebuild()
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1350, in _rebuild
    with cbook._lock_path(_fmcache):
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 1857, in _lock_path
    lock_path))
TimeoutError: Lock error: Matplotlib failed to acquire the following lock file:
        C:\Users\Никита\.matplotlib\fontlist-v300.json.matplotlib-lock
This maybe due to another process holding this lock file.  If you are sure no
other Matplotlib process is running, remove this file and try again.
```

Here is the Screenshot of error :
[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: So, remove the file and try again